# Why all users excep sys and system can connect to oracle db after database deletion on multi database environment?

Tags: oracle, oracle-12c, sysdba

I have 2 database on one server.
**I can connect to the database with normal users but cannot connect with sys and system users** and invalid username/password occurs. before that I dropped one of the databases and during dropping that database, this error occurred:

> DIM-00014: cannot open the windows NT service control
>   manager.O/S-Error:(OS 5) Access is denied

I check if I can connect `sqlplus /nolog` and `conn / as sysdba` and it did not worked and below error occurred:

> 12560:  tns protocol adapter error

anybody help!

Comment: What is the value of your `ORACLE_SID` when you try to connect? The one that you dropped?

Comment: @Marco No, I have set ORACLE_SID, ORACLE_HOME, and TNS_ADMIN correctly and other users of that database can connect to the database but sys and system cannot.

Comment: How did you attempt to drop the database, the step by step? And have you run those commands in a prompt with administrator privileges?

Comment: In spite of your assertions otherwise, if 'sqlplus / as sysdba' returns a protocol adapter error, it really means only one thing.  ORACLE_SID is not set to indicate a database for which there is a running Windows service.  If "other users" can connect, I'll bet they are using a tns connection, not the bequeath connection indicated by your failed attempt. Are they connecting with something like 'sqlplus user/pwd@mydb'?

Comment: To  @GuilhermeMesquitaX, Yes I think that is maybe one problem that causes the errors. unfortunately I ran the {DBCA} without administrator privileges. yesterday I used regedit and delete unnecessary files from HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE ->SOFTWARE->ORACLE and  HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE ->SYSTEM->CurrentControlSet->'Related Oracle Files' and now the error for sys is the same but the error for system user is "the account is locked".

Comment: To @EdStevens, when I use sqlplus and connect as {sys/mypass@mydb as sysdba}, I get the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found a solution. I changed `sys` password using `orapwd`. There is just one issue. As documentation says, the password for users which do not have `sysdba or sysoper privileges` will be expired after some time. So, to avoid this `login as sysdba` and `grant sysdba and sysoper` to the sys.

Comment: passwords for non-sysdba users are handled entirely differently from those of sysdba users.  Non-sysdba users have their passwords stored in the data dictionary, along with other properties of their account.  Passwords of sysdba users are stored in the external password file. Passwords for sysdba users never expire. Period.  There should be no need to grant sysdba and sysoper to SYS, as SYS has those privileges by definition.